# SQL import in table from temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to import from a temp file to a database table.
The problem that I am having is that even if it status = '1' when it imports into the db table, I get 0 for each and every row. Seems like I am doing something wrong. Not sure why the case statement not working.

I have the following code:

```
drop table #fixtures 

create table #fixtures(status varchar(5) )

    BULK INSERT #fixtures
    FROM 'C:\Fixtures\NewOne.txt'
    WITH 
    (
       FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t',
       ROWTERMINATOR ='\n',
       FIRSTROW = 2
    )



   insert into WaterTbl (Active)
   select  
      case 
        when ltrim(status) = '1' then 1
        else 0
      end
   from #fixtures
```

Comment: You might try:  `ltrim(rtrim(status)) = '1'` or `status like '%1%'`.

Comment: How many columns do you have in source file? Can we see few rows from it?

Comment: What collation is your database using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 select col1 = ( case         when ltrim(status) = '1' then 1
    else 0
  end)  from #fixtures
```